# Sum when column values match

Tags: sum

How can I sum all of the everything in the amount column if values in policy number column match. This is my current code, but it doesn't work.

```
select        total.*     
from          (
select        p.policyNum,
                            p.stateID,
                            p.effectiveDate,
              a.claimFreeDiscount,
                            a.homeownerDiscount,
                            a.policyZip,
                            mb.claimnumber,
                            sum(mb.amount)
                            
                from aggressive.dbo.Policy                                                  as p
              inner join Aggressive.dbo.Auto                                          as a  
                on p.policyID = a.policyID
                      left join MicrosoftPowerBI.dbo.ClaimTransactionDetail                as mb
                on p.policyid = mb.policyid
                where p.stateID = 74 and
                p.companyID = 10 and
                p.status =1
                )                                                                           as total
                group by total.mb.Amount
```

Comment: What language is this?  In what way(s) does it not work?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I'm getting this 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.'

Comment: What are your tables' schema?